# How to extract images from video files using FFmpeg without blur?

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, libav, totem

I have an `X.MTS` video file and I want to extract images from. I tried to extract with FFmpeg but quality of extracted images is not good.

```
ffmpeg -i X.MTS images/%05d.png
```

Then I tried to extract images (take screenshot) from that file with VLC and Totem (Ubuntu’s default) video players.

Results are shown below. As you see screenshot of Totem is better than VLC screenshot. Is it possible to extract images from the video using FFmpeg with good quality?

#### VLC Screenshot

[image: VLC Screenshot]

#### Totem Screenshot

[image: Totem screenshot]

Comment: Use postprocess filters.

Comment: @IporSircer tried to use them. Unfortunately result is the same.

Comment: Both totem and vlc are based on ffmpeg and use ffmpeg postprocess filters. So find out which of them do you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the first image is [interlaced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlaced_video). So perhaps simply deinterlacing would solve this issue? To do that with FFmpeg just take your command—as you have provided as an example—and add the `-deinterlace` option like this:

```
ffmpeg -i X.MTS -deinterlace images/%05d.png
```

But—according to a [comment by LordNeckbeard](https://superuser.com/questions/1274282/how-to-extract-images-from-video-files-using-ffmpeg-without-blur/1274303#comment1880048_1274303)—while the `-deinterlace` option still works, it has been depreciated in favor of the [yadif deinterlacing filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#yadif). So you can achieve similar functionality using the `-vf yadif` option like this:

```
ffmpeg -i X.MTS -vf yadif images/%05d.png
```

Comment: `-deinterlace` has been deprecated for a long time for the [yadif deinterlacing filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#yadif), so if it ever goes away use `-vf yadif` instead. If you don't like the default output of yadif it has several modes you can experiment with. There are also a few other deinterlacing filters with hard to remember names such as [bwdif](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#bwdif), [nnedi](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#nnedi), and [w3fdif](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#w3fdif).